# Does Pushbullet's MessagingExtension Service need manual stopping?

Tags: android, pushbullet

This is a simple question. I am adding Pushbullet support in my app by adding a `Service` that extends Pushbullet's `MessagingExtension` class.

Now, do I manually need to close the service inside its methods (`onMessageReceived()` and `onConversationDismissed()`) or does the `MessagingExtension` class handle it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PB dev here. I suggest not closing/stopping the service since we are binding to it (a long lived connection). Since messaging is quite chatty, having to reconnect for each message / dismissal would be wasteful. The service is very lightweight and doesn't hold any wakelocks so the impact of maintaining the connection is very minimal. Further, if Android becomes under memory pressure, the system will clear the service as needed.